# Is it possible to stub something other than a function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: serviceURL + campaignId + "/question/" + questionId + "?showDraft=" 
        + showDraft,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback(data);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to test the above code using Mocha, Sinon, and Chai. Specifically the line where it says "success". I've already tested is by passing a stub as the callback and asserted that it was called.

Now I want to test the opposite, which is if the callback is not a function. I can pass a string or array or something else but then there's now way to assert that it was not called because you cant call a string nor can you stub it.

In order to get isFunction to be false, I cant pass a stub. Any ideas?

Update:

I have already stubbed ajax. I am specifically looking at tthe line sucess. How can I test that when a non-function is passed as a callback, there is no attempt to call it?

Answer (score 2):

By stubbing the callback you are testing that jQuery's `ajax` method works. But I suspect that's not the unit under test. Also, stubbing the callback won't prevent the network call, which you probably don't want to happen in your test.

Instead you should stub `ajax()`. Then you can assert that it was called and what was passed to the function — you can test that it was called with an object containing a `success` property that points to a function.

There's an example of this in the [Sinon docs](http://sinonjs.org):

```
after(function () {
    jQuery.ajax.restore();
});

it('makes a GET request for todo items', function () {
    sinon.replace(jQuery, 'ajax', sinon.fake());
    getTodos(42, sinon.fake());

    // here you can test what was passed to the ajax including the type of 
    // the success handler
    assert(jQuery.ajax.calledWithMatch({ url: '/todo/42/items' }));
});
```